# WCF Service that sends response to client and triggers an independent function

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, async-await

I've created a WCF Service that recieves a request from (java) client and returns a string. So far it's working well, but I need to process an independent function when my service is called.

I've been reading and found that I could do this with async/await. So I've changed my code to the following:

IService:

```
 public interface IService
    {

        [OperationContract(Action = "")]        
        Task<string> receptor(string ordenFirmada);

    }
```

Service:

```
public async Task<string> receptor(string ordenFirmada)
    {
        return await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => opReceptor(ordenFirmada));
    }
public string opReceptor(string ordenFirmada)
    {
        string res = string.Empty;
        (...) //indepent process goes here
        return res;
    }
```

But when I debug it, receptor "waits" until opReceptor finishes to give the client a response. 
In other words, how can I achieve to return some string to client when calls my service and AFTER that (when client is happy processing my returned string), my service triggers a function (which is totally independent from the client call) that does something internally (client doesn't care about this, client just needs the previous string returned and closed socket).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You don't understand what await does. Very dangerous to use this feature if you don't know the first thing about it: It waits for its argument!

Comment: I thought I could use it, that's all. I'm searching for something that besides answering the client with a string, triggers some independent function and client doesn't wait 'till that process is over. Any suggestions?

Comment: If you take out the await it basically works because you stop waiting. I thought you might have tried that after the last comment. Maybe you should Google a bit for what await does and you will see that it is not needed here.

Comment: Ohhhhhh! Now I get it. Thanks.